# wget a local HTTPS site? Can I set the IP wget should use to connect to the site?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, https, debian, wget

wget is trying to connect at 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't work. Is it possible to set the IP address wget should connect to without changing my `/etc/hosts`

Changing the `/etc/hosts` creates all sorts of other problems.

I'm running Debian 8 and I get:

`ERROR: The certificate of ‘example.com’ is not trusted.`

I suppose a way to accept unsigned certificates would also do.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try --no-check-certificate option with wget.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much for this. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.